# Controlling an Arduino over the web with the lowest latency

Tags: node.js, arduino, xmpp

I have an Arduino board in a location, and a webserver.
I also have a website that is supposed to control the Arduino. What technique would allow users to take control of the Arduino board with the least amount of latency?

I have [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodejs), [socketserver](http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html), [Jabber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol) in mind to experiment with, but is this the right direction?

Answer (score 4):

You should have a look at [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) for implementing WebSockets on server- and client-side.

There's a great project called [duino](https://github.com/ecto/duino) for accessing Arduino with Node.js, you "only" have to pipe all communication through WebSockets.

**Update:** In the meantime I have published a framework for sending commands to an Arduino with Node.JS, JavaScript and WebSockets. Make sure to have a look at [Noduino](http://semu.github.com/noduino)!

Answer (score 1):

I had good luck using [node-serialport](https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport) to talk to the Arduino. Using the serial port results in very low latency, and I used it to build a photobooth. [The code](https://github.com/underbluewaters/node-photobooth) is on GitHub if you want to check it out, though it's very poorly organized as I was rushing to get this done for my wedding and well... corners were cut.